# Change the value of one column based on the value of another column

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

Lets say i have a table like so...

```
ITEM#     ItemType     SIZE
1         Car          5.20
2         Watch        2.00
3         Watch        7.50
4         Watch        6.40
5         Car          5.00
6         Car          4.30
```

I would like to select all rows but whenever the ItemType = 'Car' I would like the value for SIZE to be returned as null.

I have tried using

```
CASE When ItemType = 'Car'
Then SIZE = null
END
```

but this does not work.

Many thanks!

Comment: You do not need to assign: CASE When ItemType = 'Car' Then null END

Answer (score 3, accepted):

maybe because value where missing for other rows, try with this:

```
SELECT
    ITEM,
    ItemType,
    CASE
        WHEN ItemType = 'Car' THEN null
        ELSE Size
    END
FROM table
```

Comment: In this example SIZE would never = 'Car'

Comment: i corrected it before you made comment. Only difference between this, and what you have already tried is "else size".